# django-registration-redux and django-crispy-forms: submit button not responding

Tags: django, django-forms, django-registration

my registration_form.html is

```
{% extends '../base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
{% crispy form %}
<input type='submit' value="submit">
{% endblock %}
```

the view is in a module in an existing app. its below:

```
from registration.views import RegistrationView
from . import forms

class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    def get_form_class(self):
        return forms.LoginForm
```

the url in the urls.py file is

```
url(r'^accounts/register/$',MyRegistrationView.as_view()),
```

when the page load, on filling it, when i click submit, it does not submit.
pls what am i missing?

Comment: Note you can set `form_class = forms.LoginForm` instead of defining `get_form_class()`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if your form is not enclosed in a `<form>` tag. You should have something like:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {% crispy form %}
    <input type='submit' value="submit">
</form>
```